# Special-Characters not working in LibreOffice impress

Tags: libreoffice, special-characters

I opened a document in LibreOffice (7.2.2.2) Impress but somehow the special characters are replaced with an envelope sign. The button that should link to "insert special character" is grey and does not work at all. Also "special characters..." in the dropdown menu of "insert" is grey and not working. I just updated Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 but I don't use LibreOffice that much so I am not sure if that is linked to the problem.

I tried:

- Install the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package.
- Reinstall LibreOffice with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libreoffice`

Comment: Try to reinstall all components: `sudo apt purge libreoffice-core; sudo apt install libreoffice`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite intuitive.

Having opened Impress first click on where it says `Click to add Text` then you will have access to `Insert -> Special Character`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! that solved half of my problem, I do still have many envelopes all around my document where there used to be arrows and other characters.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate that on my system... I use LO Draw in the main. Are you able to delete the errant characters or perhaps copy paste the text required into a new slide? I would tend to the view that right clicking on the slide in the left pane and selecting `Duplicate Slide` to experiment might be a way forward leaving your basic structure intact.

Comment: It has been two years ago that I used this document. I now realize that a lot of math disappeared as well.

Comment: since the file may be corrupted, It may not be possible to replicate or assist with the side issues. As the main part of your question has been addressed, are you are to mark it as accepted so that others with the same question can find the resource easily please?